# How to write this Xpath shortly?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I need get attribute value of the element. And I am trying to access using absolute path.
`//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[23]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/img`

I want to write code in relative `xpath`. How to write that

Comment: provide html code of element

Comment: check if `img` has `id` and use it - `//img[@id="..."]`

Comment: Maybe try a XPath tutorial? Here is a basic one: http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html DOM structure this may work for you... but it's unlikely:
//*[@id="main"]//span/img